# Plotly 2D scatter continuous color for lines no effect

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

I wish to have continuously changing colors for my 2D scatter plot by specifying the values in defined markers.

```
    x = np.logspace(2, 5, num=10)
    y1  = [4.1,3.42,2.01,1.83,1.80,1.77,1.77,1.76,1.70,1.70]
    color1 = [5,5,6,7,9,12,15,21,29,45]

    y2 = [10.52,8.77,6.71,5.62,5.42,4.31,3.38,2.53,1.83,1.80]
    color2 = [5,5,6,7,9,12,15,21,29,45]
    layout = go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(),yaxis=dict(),
        legend={'traceorder':'normal'}
    )

    fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)
    for x,y,color,name in ((x,y1,color1),(x,y2,color2)):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=name,x=x, y=y,marker_line_colorscale='Hot',
                      marker_line_color=color,marker_color=color,
                            mode='lines+markers'))
    
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, )
```

Produces
[image]
As seen, the markers changed their colors, but the lines are still red and blue.

Comment: So you'd like to have a gradually changing color for the line itself?

Comment: Yes, with respect to "color1", similar to matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Comment: I see... At the time being I think the closest you'll come to something like this with plotly is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64158858/plotly-how-to-create-a-line-plot-of-a-time-series-variable-that-has-a-multiple/64163639#64163639)